# PHP search results not inserting on my table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a search module to show results from database, I am echoing out the data to check if I am receiving it from database.

here is my current output:
[image]

As you can see, the results are there but I wasn't able to display it on my table, and I also have that error for invalid argument for foreach(). Can anyone check what is the problem here?

```
    echo form_open(site_url() . '/search/get_account',array('id' => 'formSearch')); 

$data = array(
    'name'      => 'acctNum',
    'id'        => 'acctNum',
    'type'      => 'hidden',
    'value'     => set_value('acctNum',''),
);

$dataCertType = array($data);
$dataCertType[''] = '--';
if(! is_null($certType))
    foreach($certType as $rowType)
        $dataCertType[$rowType->certTypeId] = $rowType->certTypeName;
$formCertType = form_dropdown('certType', $dataCertType, set_value('certType'),'id="certType" class="dropdown"');
```

Comment: I am not able to see any data with key `certTypeId` in your echoed data. So please check with your output if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

add brackets. echo out the form drop dropdown.

```
if(! is_null($certType)){

    foreach($certType as $rowType){

        $dataCertType[$rowType->certTypeId] = $rowType->certTypeName;
       $formCertType = form_dropdown('certType', $dataCertType,set_value('certType'),'id="certType" class="dropdown"');

     echo $formCertType ; 

     }    
}
```

bonus points - do your is_null check in your controller, and then show an appropriate view.

Comment: Tried your code sir but still got the same error, and I echo-ed the $formCertType in the table already but it is still no response.

Comment: Are you returning result OR result_array from your model? If its result array then change it to result. Then you can use arrow syntax. Look at this page carefully: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html